# How to check isEmpty on a List of Lists in Thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

I have the following:

```
@Data
public class SomeClass {
   List<SomeBean> beans = new ArrayList();
}
```

If I have a `List` of `SomeClass` beans, is there an easy way to check whether the `beans` list is empty?

For example, something like this doesn't work (logically): `th:if="${#lists.isEmpty(someClass?.beans)}"`

Perhaps a utility that can flatten the lists?

I could instead put this on the server-side, but didn't know whether there was an easy way to do it on the front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these kinds of things, look at [collection selection](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-collection-selection) and [collection projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-collection-projection).  In your case an expression like this should work:

```
th:if="${#aggregates.sum(listOfSomeClass.![beans.size()]) == 0}"
```