# Thymeleaf: How to deal with complex map keys

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

I got a map of the form `Map<Bean,List<AnotherBean>>` and I need to acces a field of the key value on Thymeleaf, is there a way to do it? Or am I just doomed to look for another way to do this?
What I´ve tried so far:

```
<div th:each="entry: ${map.keySet()}">  
     <span  th:text="${entry.field}"></span>
```

and :

```
<div th:each="entry: ${map}">   
     <span  th:text="${entry.key.field}"></span>
```

Both times I got the same error:

> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:
> Property or field 'field' cannot be found on object of type
> 'java.lang.String' - maybe not public or not valid?

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Given you are using Spring and SpEL: Do selections and projections help here? See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63623608/how-to-check-isempty-on-a-list-of-lists-in-thymeleaf).

Comment: Your code works for me when I test it -- if your `Map` is in fact a `Map<Bean,List<AnotherBean>>`.  However, the error is pretty clear... you think your key is a `Bean` but it's actually a `String`.  You need to verify your `Map` again.

Comment: I ended up throwing it away and just using a list.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that `${map.keySet()}` is returning a List... Dont' know if it's a thymeleaf problem, or it resides in your data structure, but I would suggest trying something like

```
List<String> headers = new ArrayList<>();
map.forEach((key, value) -> {
    headers.add(key.getFIeld());
};
context.setVariable("tableHeaders", headers );
```

using a similar approach also for your map.values() in your template now you could iterate directly on tableHeaders and values.

```
 <div class = "container">
     <h2 th:text="${title}"></h2>
     <table id="myTable" class = "table">
         <tr>
             <th th:each = "header : ${tableHeaders}" th:text="${header}"></th>
         </tr>
          <tr th:each = "record : ${records}">
              <td th:each="element : ${record}" th:text="${element}"></td>
          </tr>
       </table>
   </div>
```

I understand this is more of a workaround, but if it doesen't pick the field in this matter you can be assured that the problem is in the Bean which compose the key parameter of you map